# How to get created/updated datetime field in response of list bases Airtable API

Tags: javascript, triggers, webhooks, airtable

I need to run some function whenever a new base is created in airtable. I found out that airtable api support webhooks but it needs baseid for creating webhook, so i can't use it for getting notification about base creation.
I am trying to poll the data but [List base Api](https://airtable.com/developers/web/api/list-bases) also don't return any info about created/updated time.
Is there any hack/info which i can use to get only new created base.

I already looked into api docs and didn't found anything useful about getting notifications for new created base.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found out there is no way to get these propeties back in response. I contacted with their support team and they said they only provide standard response back.